# IIf statement in Access 2010 to compare date field to 90 days from today

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to compare a date field in Access 2010 to 90 days from today's date. This formula will be in a text box on a report. I've tried adding the statement shown below but it asks me for the value of 'd' when I run the report.

```
IIf([DUE_DATE]>(DateAdd(d,90,Date)),[LETTER_DUE_DATE],Date)
```

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Access, dates are double, just add:

```
IIf DueDate>Date()+90, ...
```

If you must use DateAdd, d is a string:

```
DateAdd("d",90,Date)
```